# How can I pass arguments from one tab to another?

Tags: flutter, dart

My application has two tabs. One contains the Chapter and second tab contains the Lessons. The number of lessons on second tab is dynamic and depends on from which Chapter it is building. I could move from First Tab to Second using the **DefaultTabController.of(context).animateTo(1)**
But how can I pass the chapter index to second tab like the arguments in Navigator.push ?

Comment: Ideally you would use a State Management solution, like `ScopedModel`, that lets you share data across your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution could arrive with the [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package. Do not place it at the top of your widget tree if you don't need it, you'll avoid potential useless rebuilds.

Probably you want to do this:

```
class Data {
  String something;
}
```

And then at some point in your widget tree, above the page with the tabs, you use:

```
Provider(
  create: (_) => Data(),
  child: YourWidgetWithTabs()
)
```

Childs will be able to call `Provider.of<Data>(context)` to get the data. It's usually better to use Consumer which gives you more control on rebuilds and consequently it improves performance.

You will crate a proper `Data` class (not like mine, it just gives the idea).

---

The general point is to have a "data holder" at the top of the tree that you use to read/write data. If you also need to listen to changes made to the data source, use `ChangeNotifierProvider`.